# Why do I get $\alpha = \omega ^2$ in angular acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

In a 2D plane, the tangential acceleration of an object moving in uniform circular motion is, using the fact that $ v = \omega r$ :

$$a_t = \frac{v^2}{r} = \omega^2 r$$

and we know the relationship between tangential, $a_t$,  and angular, $\alpha$,  acceleration is

$$ a_t = \alpha r$$

then we have

$$\alpha = \omega ^2 $$

which is wrong, but why? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Oh, you are just making a simple understanding mistake. You did not write down the tangential acceleration. You wrote down the radial acceleration. That is, $a_r=-\omega^2r$ not $a_t$, and if the particle is doing uniform circular motion, then $a_t=0=\alpha$

Answer (score 1):

The tangential acceleration of a body in a uniform circular motion is 0 due to the fact that it's magnitude is equal to r(radius) times the angular acceleration (which is zero as the body has a constant speed and thus a constant angular velocity).The formula that you have stated for tangential acceleration is actually the one used to find the centripetal acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Deriving the velocity vector using the Leibniz rule $$\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(|\vec{v}|\hat{v})=\frac{\partial |\vec{v}|}{\partial t}\hat{v}+|\vec{v}|\frac{\partial \hat{v}}{\partial t}$$
You get two terms: the first one is the tangential velocity $\frac{\partial |\vec{v}|}{\partial t}$ directed in the velocity (tangential) direction while the second term is the modulus of the velocity times the derivative of the velocity versor. Then, deriving the versor you get $$\frac{\partial \hat{v}}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}\hat{n}$$, where $\hat{n}$ is the normal vector (with respect to the tangential one). Thus, collecting the results for the second term you get $|\vec{v}|\frac{\partial \hat{v}}{\partial t}=|\vec{v}|\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}\hat{n}=v\omega\hat{n}=\omega^2R\hat{n}$.

Finally $$\vec{a}=\vec{a_t}+\vec{a_n}=\frac{\partial |\vec{v}|}{\partial t}\hat{v}+\omega^2R\hat{n}$$